# ReactJs Async Function Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, redux-toolkit

I've a slice file called login.js and I'm dispatching a function inside login.js file by using createAsyncThunk. When I call the Class inside createAsyncThunk function it doesn't wait the response. Where am I doing mistake?

**login.js codes (slice file)**

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk("login", async (oParams, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        await AuthService.login(oParams, (response) => {
            return response;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response || e);
    }
});
```

**auth.service.js file codes**

```
import RequestProvider from '../provider/service.provider';

const login = async (payload, callback) => {
    //RequestProvider is a Class which contains parameters and sending request inside.
    new RequestProvider("POST", "login", "api_name", "companyId=100", payload, 
    (oResponse) => {
        callback(oResponse);
    });
};

const AuthService = {
    login
};

export default AuthService;
```

**service.provider.js codes;**

```
import { loginAxiosConfig } from "../../../../axiosConfig";

export default class RequestProvider {
    constructor(requestType, methodName, apiName, requestQueryParams, requestPayload, 
    callback) {
        this.requestType = requestType;
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.apiName = apiName;
        this.requestQueryParams = requestQueryParams;
        this.requestPayload = requestPayload;
        this.callback = callback;

        if (requestType === "POST") {
            this.postRequest();
        }

        if (requestType === "GET") {
            this.getRequest();
        }
    }

    postRequest() {
        if (this.methodName === "login") {
            loginAxiosConfig.post(`/${this.apiName}/${this.methodName}? 
            ${this.requestQueryParams}`, this.requestPayload).then((response) => {
                this.callback(response);
            }).catch(() => {
                this.callback(false);
            });
        } else {

        }
    }

    getRequest() {
        return this.requestType;
    }

}
```

Comment: `const login = async (payload, callback) => {` expects a callback function you have not supplied

Comment: The `AuthService.login` function also doesn't return any value.

Comment: Even if I set the callback function to AuthService.login it doesn't work. I don't know why. I've edited my question. Could you please review again?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `AuthService.login` function call in a Promise callback and pass the `resolve` function as the callback to `AuthService.login`.

```js
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  "login",
  async (oParams, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await new Promise(resolve => {
        AuthService.login(oParams, resolve);
      });
      return response;

      // or just
      // return new Promise(resolve => AuthService.login(oParams, resolve));
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response || e);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const login = async (payload, callback) => { // <-- callback is resolve
  // RequestProvider is a Class which contains parameters and sending request inside.
  new RequestProvider(
    "POST",
    "login",
    "api_name",
    "companyId=100",
    payload, 
    callback // <-- passes oResponse to resolve
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew. My issue has been resolved. But I'd like to ask a question. Why do we need to wrap AuthService.login function to Promise. I've already exist a async function inside Class?

Comment: @MLElyakan `login` is declared `async`, yes, that's only a Javascript keyword that allows the function to call `await` in *its* scope. There's no `async` code called though, and since nothing is awaited there's actually no need to declare `login` `async`. We wrap the call in a Promise so the ***resolved*** value can be returned to the *outer* scope of the Thunk. Does this make sense?

Comment: I got it Drew. Thank you for your response.